# When compiling Tensorflow with GPU support, CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH unbound variable is encountered

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow, bazel

I am following [this link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source) to compile Tensorflow with GPU support. After `./configure`, I then type in `bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package`. During the compilation, I see the following error.

```
ERROR: /home/super/.cache/bazel/_bazel_super/6fad3aac5da8510114d7933cea773172/external/nccl_archive/BUILD.bazel:139:1: Executing genrule @nccl_archive//:device_code_fatbin_h failed (Exit 1)
/bin/bash: CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH: unbound variable
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.973s, Critical Path: 0.12s
INFO: 4 processes: 4 local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I checked the `.tf_configure.bazelrc` file and the `CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH` is defined.

```
build --action_env PYTHON_BIN_PATH="/home/super/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin/python"
build --action_env PYTHON_LIB_PATH="/home/super/anaconda3/envs/tf/lib/python3.6/site-packages"
build --python_path="/home/super/anaconda3/envs/tf/bin/python"
build:xla --define with_xla_support=true
build --config=xla
build --action_env TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL="0"
build --action_env TF_NEED_ROCM="0"
build --action_env TF_NEED_CUDA="1"
build --action_env CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH="/usr/local/cuda"
build --action_env TF_CUDA_VERSION="10.0"
build --action_env CUDNN_INSTALL_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.0"
build --action_env TF_CUDNN_VERSION="7"
build --action_env TF_NCCL_VERSION=""
build --action_env TF_CUDA_COMPUTE_CAPABILITIES="5.2"
build --action_env LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64"
build --action_env TF_CUDA_CLANG="0"
build --action_env GCC_HOST_COMPILER_PATH="/usr/bin/gcc"
build --config=cuda
test --config=cuda
build:opt --copt=-march=native
build:opt --copt=-Wno-sign-compare
build:opt --host_copt=-march=native
build:opt --define with_default_optimizations=true
build:v2 --define=tf_api_version=2
```

My `.bashrc` has the following.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/bin${PATH:+:${PATH}}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-10.0/lib64${LD_LIBRARY_PATH:+:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}}
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/loca/cuda
export CUDA_TOOLKIT_PATH=/usr/local/cuda
```

My environment settings are as follows.

- bazel 0.18.0
- CUDA 10.0
- cuDNN 7.3.1
- Ubuntu 16.04

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My assumption is that you're trying to compile directly from the master branch. I was running into the same issue earlier, but after checking out a published release (v1.12.0-rc2), I was able to compile TensorFlow without anymore issues. Try `git checkout v1.12.0-rc2` then run through the `./configure` and bazel compilation again. The master branch updates very frequently. My thought is that the build was broken at the moment we were trying to install.

Comment: I had to checkout v1.11 to get it to work. Thanks for the tip.